# Gradle CI Gitlab CURL file path can't be loaded

Tags: android, gradle, curl, gitlab-ci

I am setting up upload with CURL in the Gradle CI .yml file. I am not familiar with CURL syntax so my file path keeps failing.

I initiate a repo in my project folder at the job start and my artifact is located at app/build/outputs/apk/debug/app.apk path.

When I go to app/build/outputs/apk/debug in the terminal and execute my curl script it works as expected but the path resolution fails at CI.

**Can someone advise on how to fix the path in the curl block?**

What I have now:

```
- |
      curl \
        -A "GitLab CI" \
        -F api_key="${TEST_FAIRY_KEY}" \
        -F comment="GitLab Pipeline build ${CI_COMMIT_SHA}" \
        -F file=@app\\build\\outputs\\apk\\debug\\app.apk \
        https://upload.testfairy.com/api/upload/
```

Here is what I get in the job log:

$ curl \ # collapsed multi-line command
322Warning: setting file app\build\outputs\apk\debug\app.apk  failed!
323  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
324                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
325100   497    0     0    0   497      0   1813 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--  1813
326curl: (26) read function returned funny value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After experimenting with path I discovered it should be separated with `\/` the first `\` is for escaping the next `/`. So the working path is

```
-F file=@app\/build\/outputs\/apk\/debug\/app.apk \
```